# How to trigger command execution from one terminal to another?

Tags: python, macos

I am sending a bash command using python, which creates a new process. Let's call it 'A'. After a few seconds, a new child process is created within 'A'. Let's call it 'B'.
'B' process is a command line interface. I would like to send commands to this process, from my python code.
Is that even possible?
As long as process 'B' is running, process 'A' is running as well.

I am using macOS Monterey 12.2.1.

Comment: Use the `pexpect` library for controlling interactive processes.